# Developing, testing and debugging Hadoop map/reduce jobs with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, maven, hadoop, mapreduce

What are my options for developing Java Map Reduce jobs in Eclipse? My final goal is to run my developed map/reduce logic on my amazon Hadoop cluster but I would like to test the logic on my local machine first and put break points in it before deploying it to a larger cluster.

I see there is a Hadoop Plug-in for Eclipse which looks old (correct me if I am wrong) and a company called Karmasphere had something for ecplise and Hadoop but I am not sure if that is  still available.

How do you go about developing, testing and debugging your map/reduce job with Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I develop Cassandra/Hadoop applications in Eclipse by:

1. Using maven (m2e) to gather and configure the dependencies (Hadoop, Cassandra, Pig, etc.) for my Eclipse projects
2. Creating test cases (classes in src/test/java) to test my mappers and reducers.  The trick is to build a context object on the fly using inner classes that extend RecordWriter and StatusReporter.  If you do this then after you invoke setup/map/cleanup or setup/reduce/cleanup you can assert the correct key/value pairs and context info were written by the mapper or reducer.  The constructors for contexts in both mapred and mapreduce look ugly, but you'll find the classes are pretty easy to instantiate.
3. Once you write these tests maven will invoke them automatically every time you build.
4. You can invoke the tests manually by selecting the project and doing a Run --> Maven Test.  This turns out to be really handy because the tests are invoked in debug mode and you can set breakpoints in your mappers and reducers and do all the cool things Eclipse lets you do in debug.
5. Once you're happy with the quality of your code, use Maven to build a jar-with-dependencies for that all in one jar that hadoop likes so much.

Just as a side note, I've built a number of code generation tools based on the M2T JET project in Eclipse.  They generate out the infrastructure for everything I've mentioned above and I just write the logic for my mappers, reducers and test cases.  I think if you gave it some thought you could probably come up with a set of reusable classes that you could extend to do pretty much the same thing.

Here's a sample test case class:

```
/*
 * 
 * This source code and information are provided "AS-IS" without 
 * warranty of any kind, either expressed or implied, including
 * but not limited to the implied warranties of merchantability
 * and/or fitness for a particular purpose.
 * 
 * This source code was generated using an evaluation copy 
 * of the Cassandra/Hadoop Accelerator and may not be used for
 * production purposes.
 *
 */
package com.creditco.countwords.ReadDocs;

// Begin imports 

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counters;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.OutputCommitter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordWriter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.StatusReporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptID;
import org.junit.Test;

// End imports 

public class ParseDocsMapperTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testCount() {

        TestRecordWriter    recordWriter    = new TestRecordWriter();
        TestRecordReader    recordReader    = new TestRecordReader();
        TestOutputCommitter outputCommitter = new TestOutputCommitter();
        TestStatusReporter  statusReporter  = new TestStatusReporter();
        TestInputSplit      inputSplit      = new TestInputSplit();

        try {

                // Begin test logic


                // Get an instance of the mapper to be tested and a context instance
            ParseDocsMapper mapper = new ParseDocsMapper();

            Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>.Context context = 
                mapper.testContext(new Configuration(), new TaskAttemptID(),recordReader,recordWriter,outputCommitter,statusReporter,inputSplit);

                // Invoke the setup, map and cleanup methods
            mapper.setup(context);

            LongWritable key = new LongWritable(30);
            Text value = new Text("abc def ghi");

            mapper.map(key, value, context);

            if (recordWriter.getKeys().length != 3) {
                fail("com.creditco.countwords:ParseDocsMapperTest.testCount() - Wrong number of records written ");
            }
            mapper.cleanup(context);

                // Validation:
                //
                // recordWriter.getKeys() returns the keys written to the context by the mapper
                // recordWriter.getValues() returns the values written to the context by the mapper
                // statusReporter returns the most recent status and any counters set by the mapper
                //

                // End test logic

        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("com.creditco.countwords:ParseDocsMapperTest.testCount() - Exception thrown: "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    final class TestRecordWriter extends RecordWriter<Text, IntWritable> {
        ArrayList<Text> keys = new ArrayList<Text>();
        ArrayList<IntWritable> values = new ArrayList<IntWritable>();
        public void close(TaskAttemptContext arg0) throws IOException, InterruptedException { }
        public void write(Text key, IntWritable value) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            keys.add(key);
            values.add(value);
        }
        public Text[] getKeys() {
            Text result[] = new Text[keys.size()];
            keys.toArray(result);
            return result;
        }
        public IntWritable[] getValues() {
            IntWritable[] result = new IntWritable[values.size()];
            values.toArray(result);
            return result;
        }
    };  

    final class TestRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, Text> {
        public void close() throws IOException { }
        public LongWritable getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            throw new RuntimeException("Tried to call RecordReader:getCurrentKey()");
        }
        public Text getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            throw new RuntimeException("Tried to call RecordReader:getCurrentValue()");
        }
        public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            throw new RuntimeException("Tried to call RecordReader:getProgress()");
        }
        public void initialize(InputSplit arg0, TaskAttemptContext arg1) throws IOException, InterruptedException { }
        public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return false;
        }
    };

    final class TestStatusReporter extends StatusReporter {
        private Counters counters = new Counters();
        private String status = null;
        public void setStatus(String arg0) {
            status = arg0;
        }
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
        public void progress() { }
        public Counter getCounter(String arg0, String arg1) {
            return counters.getGroup(arg0).findCounter(arg1);
        }
        public Counter getCounter(Enum<?> arg0) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    final class TestInputSplit extends InputSplit {
        public String[] getLocations() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return null;
        }
        public long getLength() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            return 0;
        }
    };

    final class TestOutputCommitter extends OutputCommitter {
        public void setupTask(TaskAttemptContext arg0) throws IOException { }
        public void setupJob(JobContext arg0) throws IOException { }
        public boolean needsTaskCommit(TaskAttemptContext arg0) throws IOException {
            return false;
        }
        public void commitTask(TaskAttemptContext arg0) throws IOException { }
        public void cleanupJob(JobContext arg0) throws IOException { }
        public void abortTask(TaskAttemptContext arg0) throws IOException { }
    };

}
```

and here's a sample maven pom.  Note that the referenced versions are a bit out of date, but as long as those versions are kept in a maven repository somewhere, you'll be able to build this project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.creditco</groupId>
  <artifactId>wordcount.example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks like a great but complicated way to do this. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with Maven at all. I wish you had the time to publish some sort of step by step guide for your approach. I bet it will be useful to many ppl.

Comment: I did start out trying to use a simpler approach: Install hadoop on your machine (the only way I could get hdfs to run) and then run your MR job in Eclipse as a Java application.  The MR job is a java class whose main method configures the mapper, reducer, etc. for a hadoop job and then submits the job to hadoop.  You can debug your program logic that way, too, but you have to figure out a way to halt on the one invocation of the mapper (or reducer) that's causing the problem and with even a small set of data that can be difficult. I found this simpler approach much too tedious.

Comment: Could you possibly share your pom.xml file and also the sample code for your step 2. I would very much appreciate that.

Comment: awesome! +1 for being in the trenches.

Answer (score 0):

I use MiniMRCluster cluster which comes with Apache. You use to start a mini Map Reduce cluster inside a unit test! HBase also has HBaseTestingUtil which is great since you start HDFS and MapReduce in roughly two lines.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Gerken - I am trying to run the Word Count job in Eclipse by running the Driver as a Java application but I get ClassNotFoundException on the Mapper. Looks to me that running as a java application, hadoop job does not get the needed Mapper and Reduce with the jar.