# Building Hadoop For Eclipse According to the Instruction

Tags: eclipse, plugins, hadoop

This Apache page http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment seems to explain how to download Hadoop, and build it. If I follow the instruction of that page, does it add the Eclipse plugin to the Eclipse as well, or that the instruction is just for building core Hadoop only?

Thanks,
Shannon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is over a year old and discusses one way to download and import hadoop source into Eclipse so that you can make changes to the core hadoop code.

If you only want to develop hadoop jobs that run on top of hadoop then you can

- Install the hadoop plugin for Eclipse (which I have never used), or
- Use maven to define the hadoop library dependencies for your code (I do this frequently).  This (plus an install of hadoop on your local machine) will let you develop, debug and test hadoop jobs in Eclipse.

So no, this page has nothing to do with the hadoop plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Do you know a good source that would instruct me as to how to go the Maven route?  I'm pretty sure I don't want to even think of using the Eclipse plugin anymore since it either doesn't work or is not included in the Hadoop download.

Comment: My answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007423/developing-testing-and-debugging-hadoop-map-reduce-jobs-with-eclipse) might be helpful.  Please post more questions as they come along.